# jQuery Selector - Children of children

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery snippets (used with `each` to iterate over a table of results):

```
$('.foo').children('.bar').children('.first_baz').text();
$('.foo').children('.bar').children('.second_baz').text();
```

I use this to access `$firstvalue` and `$secondvalue`:

```
<tr class='foo'>
<td class='bar'><span class='first_baz'>".$firstvalue."</span><span class='second_baz'>".$secondvalue."</span></td>
</tr>
```

This works but is it efficient? I suspect there is a better way to access these values... what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first_baz and second_baz elements are just with in the table and no where else in the page then you can skip the children function use the following snippet:

```
$('.first_baz').text(); 
$('.second_baz').text();
```

If the above case doesn't hold good then you can shorten the statements to

```
var parent = $('.foo'); //Get the parent context so that its not queried twice
$('.first_baz', parent).text(); 
$('.second_baz', parent).text();
```

Comment: there are a number of instances each of those classes so I am reliant on `$(this)`, given that your second example was perfect. I already had `$(this)` assigned to `self` so `$('.first_baz', self).text();` works perfectly. Using the context is quite efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could cache all the `.bar`.

```
var bar = $('.foo').children('.bar')
bar.children('.first_baz').text();
bar.children('.second_baz').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but this should be more efficient.

```
$('.foo .bar .first_baz').text();
$('.foo .bar .second_baz').text();
```

Comment: It isn't.  Sizzle works right to left and has optimizations for ID and element selectors.  The order of the class selections or combination thereof, I predict, would have no impact on performance, and if it does, it'll be a negative one.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.first_baz').text()
```

if you don't need the parent structure,
or

```
$('tr.foo > td.bar > span.first_baz').text()
```

if you do.